# Categorising points and adding a color bar

Tags: matlab

I have  a matrix.

```
Mat_=[ x y z intensity];

e.g., intensity= rand(100,1)
```

Now I want to colorise and catergorise  my points with respect to intensity. say I want 6 or 10 classes. I also want to show it with colorbar. what is the best way to do it.

Comment: What do you want your output to look like? What do you mean by "my points"? What have you tried?

Comment: why all CAPS in question title ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want this:
Note that I don't cluster the data into pieces, I just plot them in the colorbar with the intensity value they have. You may want to change that, but I don't think its very difficult to do ;) (tip: `mod` may help).

PD: well `kmeans` also would work

```
% Create data
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-2:.2:2, -2:.2:2);                                
Z = X .* exp(-X.^2 - Y.^2);

intensity= rand(size(X));

%Get max and min
m=min(min(intensity));
M=max(max(intensity));

%set colorbar property
caxis([m M]); 
colorbar();

%get colors by intensity
colors=zeros(size(X,1),size(X,2),3);
cmap=colormap('jet'); %change for other colormaps
for i=1:size(X,1)
    for j=1:size(X,2)
        colors(i,j,:)=cmap(round(intensity(i,j)*(size(cmap,1)-1)+1),:);     
    end
end
%plot
hold on
for i=1:size(X,1)
    for j=1:size(X,2)
       plot3(X(i,j),Y(i,j),Z(i,j),'.','Color',colors(i,j,:));  
    end
end
hold off
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `kmeans` to cluster `intensity` into desired number of clusters. Then cluster `[x y z]` according to the indices obtained from clustering intensity (assuming there is one-to-one correspondence between `[x y z]` and `intensity`). Then maybe assign different colors to each cluster and then display.